# Bootstrap 4 Card images not displaying

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to learn and test bootstrap 4. I was trying to create cards but images wont show for them. I only have one image in the first card at this moment but the point is the image still wont render. Below is my code pen linked to view what I have written. Thank you for any help in advance

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/cody-blackwood/pen/ZVaMyo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/main.css">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1 class="display-2 text-info ">Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://imgur.com/gallery/A8eQsll" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The img src isn't an image.. it's an imgur html page.

Answer (score 2):

Your image tag sources aren't pointing to actual image files. See the code example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/main.css">
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1 class="display-2 text-info ">Projects</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A8eQsll.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```